# Google Books API not returning the same as displayed on browser (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, http, google-books-api

I am building a book app with Flutter for Android and iOS. I am using Google Books API to retrieve book data, but I have noticed something strange which I dont understand. If we look at the book data displayed in chrome browser (https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/b3GuDwAAQBAJ), we can see that the content (eg. field *categories*) is different than what I get when calling http response and printing out it's body. In addition to that, it also seems like unicode characters (eg. from *description*) are not sent.

[image: Data displayed on the browser]

[image: The obtained Response body]

The code that I'm using to get the API data can be seen below:

```
Response result = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
if (result.statusCode == 200) {
  final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(result.bodyBytes));
  if (jsonResponse["totalItems"] == 0) {
    return List.empty();
  }

  //this prints out the content in above image
  print(result.body.toString());

  final booksMap = jsonResponse['items'];
  List<dynamic> books = booksMap.map((i) => Book.fromJson(i)).toList();
  return books;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/b3GuDwAAQBAJ gives different data than your usual search query (eg. https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780143123231). I do not know the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the API response in raw form due to which unicode are present

[Raw Form image from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9VXD.png)

but when you get api response you can parse into json, By parsing json that unicodes are removed and data is in proper format

if you use `json Formatter` extension in chrome you  can see that the data in chrome in Json form and the response from api when you are hitting api by code are same.

[Data in Json Form in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7iA9.png)

in the application code , you set  `headers: {'content-type': 'application/json;` thats why u received Json data code. and its not problem because you will use this data into your application,

you can see more content types [here](https://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/api_gateway/yai10-5/10-5_API_Gateway_webhelp/index.html#page/api-gateway-integrated-webhelp/content_type.html)

> Blockquote

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask you a favor? Can you [edit] your answer to include the data in _text_ format, instead of as _screenshots_? You can use Markdown to format them as code for readability. That will make the data easier to read and reference.